# How to express a function mapping an integer to the multiple $3$-dimensional space?

Tags: functions, notation

I want to define a function $f$ mapping an integer $n$ to $\underbrace{\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3}_n$.

Is it correct to express the function $f$ as
$$
f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^{3\times\mathbb{N}} ~ ?
$$
For me, it is some weird. I want to define a function $f:n\mapsto\mathbb{R}^n$ in a form of ***domain to domain***. Is there a way to express the function $f$ well?

---

For example, $f(3)$ gives three $3$-vectors, $f(10)$ gives ten $3$-vectors, and so forth, where the $3$-vector implies a vector having $3$ elements.

For a detail example, $f(2)=\{(1,2,3), (10,5,3)\}$.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. Can you give a specific example of input values and output values of the question? For example, what might the values of $f(1)$ and $f(2)$ and $f(7)$ be for your function?

Comment: What does $\underbrace{\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3}_n$ even mean?

Comment: A simple definition is $n\mapsto (n,n,n,\ldots ,n,n,n)$.

Comment: @LeeMosher, Asaf Karagila I edited my question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Is it fine if I define a function by an element in domain $\mapsto$  element in range, rather than domain $\to$ codomain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that depends on how you want to treat things.

In general, you can talk about $X^{<\Bbb N}$ as the collection of finite sequences from $X$, which then you can choose to formalize as a subset of $X^\Bbb N$ where every function is eventually $0$ (you can even declare the first coordinate of each function as "its length", to avoid confusion (although it might introduce other difficulties).

So it seems to me that $f\colon\Bbb{N\to(R^3)^{<N}}$.

Comment: I first noticed the notation like $(\mathbb{R}^3)^{<\mathbb{N}}$, thank you.

Comment: The standard notation in theoretical computer science and in semigroup theory is $X^*$ (the free monoid of base $X$), but in this context you may have to explain this notation to avoid any confusion with dual spaces.